# mock GetClaimsPrincipal().Identity

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, claims-based-identity

I am not able to find the mock the below lines of code.

```
ClaimsPrincipalFactory userClaimsPrincipal = new UserClaimsPrincipalFactory();
System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity claimIdentity = userClaimsPrincipal.GetClaimsPrincipal().Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
```

When I try to mock, I am getting error

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll but was not handled in user code

in below code.

```
public class UserClaimsPrincipalFactory : ClaimsPrincipalFactory
{
    protected override ClaimsPrincipal OnGetClaimsPrincipal()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User;
    }
}
```

Mock I tried

```
Mock<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory> mockUserClaimsPrincipal = new Mock<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
mockUserClaimsPrincipal
    .Setup(ucp => ucp.GetClaimsPrincipal().Identity).Returns("Need to set");
```

Any one help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `ClaimsPrincipalFactory` a custom class? If it is can you include a definition of the class.

Comment: What are you really trying to test? Is the `claimIdentity` being generated to be part of a bigger test?

Comment: That exception is related to the tight coupling to `HttpContext`

Answer (score 1):

IF the below code...

```
ClaimsPrincipalFactory userClaimsPrincipal = new UserClaimsPrincipalFactory();
ClaimsIdentity claimIdentity = userClaimsPrincipal.GetClaimsPrincipal().Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
```

is being used as part of a larger test where you have need for the `claimIdentity` variable then you need to abstract the `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` because the concrete implementation of this class is tightly coupled to `HttpContext` which would be null during your test unless you also mocked the `HttpContext` (which you shouldn't do: [Don't mock HttpContext: He doesn't like to be mocked!](https://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2010/08/19/Dont-mock-HttpContext))

Provided the end goal is to get a `ClaimsPrincipal/ClaimsIdentity` then you can abstract that requirement into a service.

```
public interface IClaimsPrincipalFactory {
    ClaimsPrincipal GetClaimsPrincipal();
}
```

that way you can test without the direct dependency on `HttpContext`.

The assumption here is that you have direct control of the `ClaimsPrincipalFactory` class and can refactor it....

```
public abstract class ClaimsPrincipalFactory : IClaimsPrincipalFactory {
    public ClaimsPrincipal GetClaimsPrincipal() {
        ClaimsPrincipal result = OnGetClaimsPrincipal();
        //...other code
        return result;
    }
    protected abstract ClaimsPrincipal OnGetClaimsPrincipal();
}
```

With that done a unit test can look like....

```
[TestMethod]
public void Factory_Should_Get_Claims_Principal() {
    //Arrange
    var fakeIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
    var mockUserClaimsPrincipal = new Mock<IClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
    mockUserClaimsPrincipal.Setup(ucp => ucp.GetClaimsPrincipal().Identity).Returns(fakeIdentity);

    IClaimsPrincipalFactory userClaimsPrincipal = mockUserClaimsPrincipal.Object;
    System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity claimIdentity = userClaimsPrincipal.GetClaimsPrincipal().Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;

    //Act
    //...other code that uses the claimIdentity


    //Assert
    //...other assertions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com). 
`Isolate.WhenCalled()` mocks `OnGetClaimsPrincipal()`, so it doesn't touch HttpContext at all, and returns needed `ClaimsPrincipal`. See the example:

```
public void TestGetClaimsPrincipal()
{
    //Arrange 
    var claims = new List<Claim>();
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Name"));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "name@gmail.com"));
    var myIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    var myPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(myIdentity);
    var target = new UserClaimsPrincipalFactory();
    Isolate.NonPublic.WhenCalled(target, "GetClaimsPrincipal").WillReturn(myPrincipal);

    //Act
    var result = Isolate.Invoke.Method(target, "GetClaimsPrincipal") as ClaimsPrincipal;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Name", result.Identity.Name);
}
```

Hope it helps!